# Obtener marca y modelo del Motherboard de la Pc en java?

Tags: java

Como puedo averiguar la marca y modelo del Motherboard de la pc en la cual se ejecuta mi programa Java? gracias.

Comment: Hola Facundo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] y [ask] para aprender más del sitio y como hacer preguntas de calidad. Tu pregunta puede ser cerrada por estar basada en opiniones ya que lo que preguntas es una recomendación de librería y cada usuario puede darte una respuesta dada su experiencia u opinon. Has de objetivizar al maximo una pregunta. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Hola puedes utilizar la libreria [jMWI](http://henryranch.net/software/jwmi-query-windows-wmi-from-java/) despues solo haces la consulta de esta manera:

```
String motherboardName = getWMIValue("Select Name from Win32_BaseBoard", "Name");
```

Aqui puedes mirar como obtener mas datos [Win32_BaseBoard](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394072(v=vs.85).aspx)